# How to capture audio buffer only 8 bytes every each 20ms?

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I'm capturing a microphone stream using Javascript Web Audio API, I'm sending the data by UDP transport, but before sending I need to convert the data to 8 frames every each 20ms (160 size total). Does anyone have an example or did it before?

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then((stream)=>{

        micStream.setStream(stream);

        const context = new AudioContext();
        const processor = context.createScriptProcessor(16384,1,1);
        const mediaStreamSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        mediaStreamSource.connect(processor);
        processor.connect(context.destination);

      processor.onaudioprocess = (e) =>{
        try{
          if(!this.isValidAudio()){
            context.close();
          }else{
            const leftData = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            const buffer = this.convertFloat32ToInt16(leftData); 

            this.ws.send(buffer, (result)=>{
                console.log('Result >> ', result);
            }, false);
          }
        }catch(error){
          console.log('error >> ', error)
        }
      };
    }).catch((e)=>{
      console.log('stream error >> ', e);
    })
```

Comment: I resolved it using wasm, AudioWorkletProcessor with a RingBuffer implementation.

Comment: I recent publish a NPM lib to makes it easy https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasm-ring-buffer